# JS: Display certain div if browser is IE

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have this react project that doesn't work in Internet Explorer, and we don't intend it to work in IE.

So when rendering the index.html there is the usual `root div` that renders react.

**I want not to render that `root div` when browser is IE but a different div, with a message warning that the app doesn't work in IE**

I can know if the browser is IE like so:

`const isIE = !!window.MSInputMethodContext && !!document.documentMode`

So I'm trying to change the html div output depending of `isIE` and I'm not quite sure how.

Logic:

if `isIE - true` render `<div id="root"></div>`

if `!isIE - false` render `<div>Browser not supported</div>`

Tried something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <% _.map(css, (item) => { %><link href="<%= item %>" rel="stylesheet"><% }) %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        const isIE = !!window.MSInputMethodContext && !!document.documentMode;
        if (isIE) { document.getElementById('root').innerHTML += '<p>IE!!</p>' } // or something similar
        </script>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script>window.__ENVIRONMENT__ = Object.freeze(<%= JSON.stringify(environment) %>) 
        </script>
        <% _.map(js, (item) => { %><script src="<%= item %>"></script><% }) %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also tried a logic returning the html as a string like so:

```
<script>
  if (isIE) { return '<div>Browser not supported</div>'; }
  else { return '<div id="root"></div> }
</script>
```

And this

```
  const IEdiv = '<div>This is IE</div>';
  const rootDiv = '<div id="root"></div>';
  if (isIE) { IEdiv.append('body'); }
  else { rootDiv.append('body'); }
```

None of this works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React shouldn't work out of the box with any version of IE as far as I can tell. It requires (or at least used to require) `react-app-polyfill` to get anywhere.

You're also going to have problems with `const` as it's only supported by IE11. If the only version of IE you're concerned with is IE11 you should be fine for this.

---

**UPDATED ANSWER**

I created a sample myself to see what I could do. I first experimented with loading the `<div>` into the page with JS, and hit a nasty IE error in being unable to add elements to the document.

So I changed my approach back to yours - editing the existing `<div>`. The problem isn't your code, the problem is that your script is being ran before the `<div>` is present in the DOM (to be accessed). Put the `<div>` above the script (or move the JS to an external file and load it in) and it should work as you intend it to.

Here's my sample for reference:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script>
          var isIE = !!window.MSInputMethodContext && !!document.documentMode;
          console.warn(isIE);
          if (isIE) { 
            var root = document.getElementById('root');
            root.innerHTML += 'IE!!';
          }
          else {
            var root = document.getElementById('root');
            root.innerHTML += 'hello hello hello';
            // you may also need to defer React being loaded in
          }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually your answer if we'd want to make it work in IE but we don't. I just want to show a simple html instead the root div when it detects that it's IE. Nothing fancy.

Comment: The problem is browser detection is a tricky question. When you factor in loading React (or any other deferred library) it gets more complicated. That said, I ran some tests and I think I found your problem. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Took a slightly different way but in the end DOM manipulation was the way to go. Thank you.